# How to go to another page in codeigniter using href link

Tags: php, codeigniter

There is one controller in my project called Welcome in that there are two functions, one is index() which load the home page called interior and the other function is architect() which loads the architect page.

```
<a class="catname activecat" href= "<?php echo base_url(''); ?>">Interior</a> 

       <a class="catname" href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/architect'); ?>">Architect</a>
```

The problem is welcome/architect is not working and it is not going to the architect page.

My Welcome controller has the following codes:

```
public function index()
    {   
        $this->load->model("Interior_listing_model","interior");
        $articles = $this->interior->interior_list();

        // Load Interior Listing View
        $this->load->view("interior/interior",["articles"=>$articles]);
    }

    public function architect()
    {   
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model("Interior_listing_model","interior");
        $articles = $this->interior->architect_list();

        // Load Interior Listing View
        $this->load->view("architect/architect",["articles"=>$articles]);
    }
```

Comment: I am right now on interior page and would like to go to architect page by clicking on that link on the interior page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Change like this..

<a class="catname" href="<?php echo base_url();?>/welcome/architect">Architect</a>
```

Diffference between base and site url:

```
echo base_url(); // http://example.com/website
echo site_url(); // http://example.com/website/index.php
```

I think your htaccess is a problem

```
Steps To Remove index.php using .htaccess:-

Step:-1  Open the file config.php located in application/config path.  Find and Replace the below code in config.php  file.

//  Find the below code

$config['index_page'] = "index.php"

//  Remove index.php

$config['index_page'] = ""
Step:-2  Go to your CodeIgniter folder and create .htaccess  file.


 Path:

Your_website_folder/
application/
assets/
system/
user_guide/
.htaccess <--------- this file
index.php
license.txt
Step:-3  Write below code in .htaccess file

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
Step:-4  In some cases the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. To solve this issue just open the file config.php located in application/config and then find and replace the code as:

//  Find the below code

$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"

//  Replace it as

$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

Comment: check your link  http://example.com/website/index.php/welcome/architect is working or not

Comment: will you remove index.php using htaccess then check your htaccess thats the problem.

Comment: okay now it goes to the next page but it is not taking the css, i.e the page is all distorted.

Answer (score 0):

In your `config.php`, `$config['base_url'] = '127.0.0.0/newbluemasons/';`
In your `routes.php`, `$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';`
Try this, I'm already did some experiments..

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'/' ?>">Interior</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/architect' ?>">Architect</a>
```

Comment: I have set my base url in the config file as $config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/newbluemasons/';  but still it does not work.

Comment: How if you try direct call in your browser 127.0.0.1/newbluemasons/welcome/architect ? Is this work?

Comment: No, even if I call directly, it does not wok.

Comment: But if I change the $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome'; to the new controller which is the architect controller, it then works.

Comment: Keep your default_controller to 'welcome', try <a class="catname" href="<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/architect">Architect</a> or <a class="catname" href="<?php echo site_url();?>/architect">Architect</a> ?

Comment: unfortunately the new modifications show "Page not found"

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

HTML:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('about-us'); ?>"
```

Config/Routs.php

```
$route['about-us'] = "welcome/aboutus";
```

Controller function

```
public function aboutus()
{
    $this->load->view('about');
}
```

Create about.php

Hope this will help you!